# get first row of group by clause in query sqlserver

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have a list of doucments in a database, some belong to a group, some don't. When the doucment belongs to a group I want the Group name to appear as the doucment name (not the actual doucment name --see case statement) in a list (together with all the other doucments). I want the group name to appear only once (using the ID of the first doucment)
Say i have

```
Cat    DocName        DocID
---------------------------
3      Doucmnt1         4
3      Document2        5
3      Document Group   6
3      Document Group   7
```

I want in the above list 'Document Group' to appear only once with ID 6. Thanks!

I have the following query:

```
SELECT Docs.DocID, Docs.Category, 
         CASE WHEN Docs.Group IS NULL THEN Docs.DocName 
              ELSE GroupDocs.GroupName 
         END AS DocumentName, Docs.DocID 
    FROM Docs 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN GroupDocs 
            ON Docs.GroupDoc = GroupDocs.GroupID 
    WHERE Docs.DocCategory = @DocCategory
```

Comment: Your SQL case statement can be replaced with: COALESCE(GroupDocs.GroupName, Docs.DocName) AS DocumentName,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later you can use a ranking function:

```
With NumberedDocs As
    (
    Select Docs.DocId, Docs.Category
        , Coalesce( GroupDocs.GroupName, Docs.DocName ) As Name
        , Row_Number() Over( Partition By Coalesce( GroupDocs.GroupName, Docs.DocName ) Order By Docs.DocId ) As Num
    From Docs
        Left Join GroupDocs
            On GroupDocs.GroupId = Docs.GroupDoc
    Where Docs.DocCategory = @DocCategory
    )
Select DocId, DocCategory, Name
From NumberedDocs
Where Num = 1
```

Comment: many thanks for your help. I applied this solution and all works ok.

Answer (score 0):

How is the solution

```
SELECT  DocID,
        Category,
        DocName,
        CASE WHEN n = 1 THEN GroupName ELSE '' END AS GroupName,
FROM    (
         SELECT Docs.DocID,
                Docs.Category,
                Docs.DocName,
                ISNULL(GroupDocs.GroupName, '') AS GroupName,
                Docs.DocID,
                n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GroupDocs.GroupName
                                      ORDER BY Docs.DocId)
         FROM   Docs
                LEFT OUTER JOIN GroupDocs
                    ON Docs.GroupDoc = GroupDocs.GroupID
         WHERE  (Docs.DocCategory = @DocCategory)
        ) data
ORDER BY data.GroupName, data.DocID
```

Answer (score 0):

First, prepare the list of documents with the document names replaced with group names, where needed. Then group the result set, among other things, by `GroupDoc` and either `DocID` (for single documents) or `NULL` (for document groups).

And here's how:

```
SELECT
  DocCategory,
  DocumentName,
  DocID = MIN(DocID)
FROM (
  SELECT
    d.DocID,
    d.DocCategory,
    DocumentName = COALESCE(g.GroupName, d.DocName),
    d.GroupDoc
  FROM Docs d
    INNER JOIN GroupDocs g ON d.GroupDoc = g.GroupID
  WHERE d.DocCategory = @DocCategory
) s
GROUP BY
  DocCategory,
  DocumentName,
  GroupDoc,
  CASE WHEN GroupDoc IS NULL THEN DocID END
```